# xpath expression to select text from link with sub divs

Tags: javascript, regex, xpath, extjs

I have a TA case where i find an element by xpath (really long one)

```
$x("//tr[./td[contains(@class, 'description_short') and .//a[contains(@class, 'descShort') and normalize-space(text()) = normalize-space('xxxxxxxxx')]]]/.//img[starts-with(@id, 'tocart_')]")$x("//tr[./td[contains(@class, 'description_short') and .//a[contains(@class, 'descShort')]]]/.//img[starts-with(@id, 'tocart_')]")
```

It no longer works because somone came with the briliant idea to highlight the words in the link name so text() returns null.

The new text is :

```
<a href="#" class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort"><b class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort"><b class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort">MDI,</b></b> P<b class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort"><b class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort">MDI,</b></b> <b class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort">Isocyanat,MDF,</b> <b class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort">Huntsman</b></a>
```

The old was:

```
<a href="#" class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort"><b class="x-dig-articleDetailSpx descShort">xxxxxx</a>
```

I have no idea how to get the text from that new mess... anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. you can use the string() function instead of text()

Kinda simple.